# Is it possible to preserve text alignment when reading from html using pandoc?

Tags: html, formatting, pandoc

When parsing the html, text alignment on the p elements is stripped in the process. When reading the source for the html reader, it seems that there is nothing picking up on text alignment outside table cells, but I am not fluent in Haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. The pandoc document model does not allow for alignment other than in tables, so the alignment information is simply ignored.